# Differentiability of tempered distributions over $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: functional-analysis, distribution-theory

One of the topics I find interesting in physics is the time evolution of improper quantum states (physicists call them kets). My question to this mathematical community is:

In what **exact sense** is a mapping $\phi:\mathbb{R}\to \mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R}^3)$, $t\mapsto\phi(t)$ continuous and furthermore differentiable in the variable/parameter "$t$"? ($\mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R}^3)$ is of course the topological dual of the Schwartz test function space)

Comment: DO you know the norm on a functional? If so, the distance between two functionals $\phi (t)$ and $\phi (s)$ is $||\phi (t)-\phi (s)||$.

Comment: @Behnam. What is the norm on $\mathcal S'(\mathbb R^3)$?

Comment: I assume that $\mathcal{S}$ is the Schwartz space. To talk about continuity, you must assign a topology, or definition of closeness in the space $\mathcal{S}'$. A usual base for this sort of spaces is the collection of translation of sets $V_{f}(\delta)=\{u\in \mathcal{S}'\mid |\langle u,f \rangle|<\delta\}$, for $f\in \mathcal{S}$. This is the general philosophy, look for some topology.

Comment: So, if $L:X \rightarrow R$ is a linear map from a normed space to reals, then $||L||:=\sup _{x \in X, \|x\| \leq 1} L(x) $

Comment: Here your $X$ is the space of smooth functions on $R^3$.

Comment: Which is not a normed space!

Comment: Dear @Behnam, you kindly noticed the possibility of giving a topology in a space of operators, but $\mathcal{S}$ is not normed, but quasi-normed.

Comment: Why quasi norm only?

Comment: The "norms" in $\mathcal{S}$ are $\lVert f\rVert_{\alpha,\beta}=\sup_x|x^\alpha D^\beta f|$ for every multi-index.

Answer (score 2):

**Definition:** $\phi : \mathbb R \to \mathcal S'(\mathbb R^3)$ is continuous if $\phi(t) \to \phi(t_0)$ whenever $t \to t_0$.

But what does $\phi(t) \to \phi(t_0)$ mean, i.e. how is convergence in $\mathcal S'(\mathbb R^3)$ defined?

**Definition:** $u_\lambda \to u_0$ when $\lambda \to 0$ if $\langle u_\lambda,
 \rho \rangle \to \langle u_0, \rho \rangle$ for every $\rho \in \mathcal S(\mathbb R^3).$

With $\langle u, \rho \rangle$ I mean the application of the tempered distribution $u$ on the testfunction $\rho$.

---

For differentiability we can just use the normal definition.
$$
\phi'(t_0) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\phi(t_0+h) - \phi(t_0)}{h}$$
meaning that
$$\langle \phi'(t_0), \rho \rangle 
= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\langle \phi(t_0+h) - \phi(t_0), \rho \rangle}{h}
= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\langle \phi(t_0+h), \rho \rangle - \langle \phi(t_0), \rho \rangle}{h}
.$$

Comment: Remark: For your definition of continuity it is essential that $\mathbb R$ is a metric space.

Comment: @amsmath. I hope that still is the case. :-D But could you explain why that is essential?

Comment: Well, if $\phi : T\to\mathcal S'(\mathbb R^3)$, where $T$ is just some topological space, you cannot characterize continuity by convergence.

Comment: @amsmath. Not by sequential convergence. But by as I understand, convergence in a net is sufficient. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I am sorry I cannot address you with @. It just doesn't work... Well, as far as I can remember, you are right. However, you did not refer to net convergence at all in your answer. But in fact, you do not have to do this: A map $f : X\to Y$ between a metric space and a topological space is continuous if and only if it is sequentially continuous. That was what I tried to point you to.

Comment: The reason that you cannot address me is that I'm the author of the answer post; I will be noted anyway about all comments to my post.

Comment: Ahhh, thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

The topology one should use on $\mathscr{S}'(\mathbb{R}^d)$ is not the weak-$\ast$ topology but rather the strong topology. It is the locally convex topology defined by the family of seminorms
$$
||\phi||_A=\sup_{f\in A}|\phi(f)|
$$
indexed by bounded subsets $A$ of Schwartz space $\mathscr{S}(\mathbb{R}^d)$. Saying that a subset $A$ is bounded means that for all multiindex $\alpha$ and all nonnegative integer $k$,
$$
\sup_{f\in A}\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}^d}\langle x\rangle^k|\partial^{\alpha}f(x)|\ <\ \infty\ .
$$

Now continuity of $t\mapsto \phi(t)$ at $t_0$ means that for all bounded set $A$,
$$
\lim_{t\rightarrow t_0}||\phi(t)-\phi(t_0)||_A=0\ .
$$

Finally, differentiability at $t_0$ with derivative equal to some distribution $\psi$ in $\mathscr{S}'(\mathbb{R}^d)$ means that for all bounded $A$,
$$
\lim_{t\rightarrow t_0}||(t-t_0)^{-1}[\phi(t)-\phi(t_0)]-\psi||_A=0\ .
$$